# using a if statement to qualify a table entry, then pull another entry in the same table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to pull an entry in the table column, called `Reason`.  If the `reasoncode` field has an entry of `"transfer"`, I would like to pull several other entries for the same person in the same table where the `positiontoeffectdate <'30000101'`.  I see several case statements and if statements, but not able to pull my data in SQL.

```
select * from mytablename
where personlastname ='test' and positiontoeffectdate <'30000101' 
and reasoncode <>'transfer'
```

This is information I need above, but it depends on a previous record in the same table but in another record where the reason code is equal to "transfer".  If this field is not equal to transfer, I do not need to pull the data; it should return blank.

Can anyone assist?

Thanks!

VB3641

Comment: Can you add a description of the table to the question? Some sample data and expected output would help too.

Comment: personidno  lastname         positionreason           positiontoeffectdate

Comment: personidno     lastname    positionreason    positiontoeffectdate               459                 Joseph       Transfer               3000-01-01                        459                 Joseph        Implementation    2015-040401                                                                                                                I need to pull the position for Implementation, but only if the positionreason=transfer and positiontoeffectdate='30000101'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your intent correct you want to pull the records for a person from the table that meets the condition `positiontoeffectdate < '30000101'` if and only if there is another record with `reasoncode = 'transfer'` for the same person. If this is the case, one way to do it is to use an `exists` predicate with a correlated subquery:

```
select * from mytablename m
where personlastname ='test' and positiontoeffectdate < '30000101' 
and reasoncode <>'transfer'
and exists (
    select 1 
    from mytablename 
    where personlastname = m.personlastname 
      and reasoncode = 'transfer'
    )
```

Comment: Yes!!  That did it!  I will exists to my skill set.                                                                                                           Thank you!

Comment: @VB3641, if this post helped you then at least vote ap for the answer

Comment: I would love to vote for you...I have looked several places and do not exactly see where to vote for you...I am new to the site so forgive me...I will look some more

Comment: @VB3641As a new user you can't vote yet (casting votes requires a bit of reputation) but I appreciate the thought. If the answer solved your problem you can however mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark on the left side of the answer.